# Is it guaranteed that v.begin() + v.size() == v.end() for C++ vector v?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I try to insert `value` into C++ vector `v` before `i`-th element (or after element `(i-1)`). The code is very simple

```
v.insert(v.begin() + i, value);
```

I am sure that this statement works when `i` is between 0 inclusively and `v.size()` exclusively. Also, I believe that when `i` is strictly greater than `v.size()` or negative, the statement has undefined behaviour. But what if `i == v.size()`? Is `v.begin() + i` a valid iterator then? Is it guaranteed that `v.begin() + v.size() == v.end()`?

If it is guaranteed, could you reference the exact parts of the Standard? Also, if the guarantees change between standard versions, it would be useful to know these changes.

Without these guarantees I probably should use the following code:

```
if (i == v.size()) {
    v.insert(v.end(), value); // or just v.push_back(value);
} else {
    v.insert(v.begin() + i, value);
}
```

But it would be more succinct to use just one line as in the beginning of this question. In practice, the code from the beginning of this question works, but I want to be sure that it works everywhere. I tried to search the Standard but could not find this property of a random access iterator.

Comment: You appear to be asking two different questions here. One on the operation of insert(), and one on comparing iterators.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I hope no, insert is just application. We should provide it a valid iterator, then it works fine. The only possible valid value of v.begin() + v.size() is v.end(). But I am not sure that it is guaranteed valid.

Comment: "Just because you're paranoid doesn't mean they aren't after you.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated on [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

> pos   -   iterator before which the content will be inserted. **pos may be the end() iterator**

so yes you can use `end()`. As for your another question:

> Is it guaranteed that v.begin() + v.size() == v.end()?

yes it is, otherwise this loop:

```
for( auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it ) ...
```

would not work properly as it must execute `++it` exactly `vec.size()` times.

Comment: Your proof with for loop example looks valid. Could you additionally cite the Standard about equivalence of `+x` operation for a random access iterator to `x` operations `++`? It is perfectly logical to be so but I need a bit more hard proof.

Comment: Is this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator good enough?

Comment: Very good table, very good explanation. I looked for exactly this table in the Standard and could not find it. Could you help me locate it there?

Comment: Open "24.2.7 Random access iterators" from http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf you will find the table there